# How to access this JSON object field in Github actions?

Tags: arrays, json, github-actions

I'm trying to access `github.event` context which is in a json object format below:

```json
{
  event: {
    after: 
    base_ref: 
    before: 
    commits: [
      {
        author: {
          email: 
          name: 
          username: 
        },
        committer: {
          email: 
          name: 
          username: 
        },
        message:
     ] ,
   },
}
```

I'm struggling trying to access and retrieve the `author` +`committer` email, name, and username fields.

I'm able to retrieve the message of the commit like so: `github.event.commits[0].message`, but cannot access the author and committer objects.

How can I access the embedded json objects within the array inside `github.event` ?

EDIT: I've tried the following:
`github.event.commits[0].author.name`

and other similar actions, but no luck.

Comment: Please show the YAML you have tried and the error message you got.

Comment: Please see my update, no error message. Just an empty string as the query im using doesn't actually target the json field im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you would need to convert the `author` and `committer` objects to JSON, using `env` variables.

Here is an example using `jq` to get the values:

```yaml
      - name: Other variables with ENV
        run: |
          echo "Commits:" $COMMITS
          echo "Message:" $MESSAGE
          echo "Author Email:" $(echo $AUTHOR | jq -r '.email')
          echo "Author Name:" $(echo $AUTHOR | jq -r '.name')
          echo "Author Username:" $(echo $AUTHOR | jq -r '.username')
          echo "Committer Email:" $(echo $COMMITTER | jq -r '.email')
          echo "Committer Name:" $(echo $COMMITTER | jq -r '.name')
          echo "Committer Username:" $(echo $COMMITTER | jq -r '.username')
        env:
          COMMITS: ${{ toJSON(github.event.commits[0]) }}
          MESSAGE: ${{ toJSON(github.event.commits[0].message) }}
          AUTHOR: ${{ toJSON(github.event.commits[0].author) }}
          COMMITTER: ${{ toJSON(github.event.commits[0].committer) }}
```

You can check the tests I made here:

- workflow run [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/6779341238?check_suite_focus=true)
- workflow file [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester36.yml).

Comment: is there a way to get everything in `github` into a JSON using jq?

Comment: You can get the whole github context in a JSON by using `${{ toJSON(github) }}`, you could then use a variable and jq to manage it as you wish. I've got a sample workflow here [manipulating github contexts](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/24-contexts.yml).

Comment: thanks I found it too.. I think it should be spelt as `toJson` right? I'm using Gitea actually, but it is same/quite simliar with GitHub.